# PHP - Finding Google search data information (Estimated traffic etc) for Keywords

Tags: javascript, php, google-ads-api

I'm trying to find Google search information (Traffic mainly) for particular keywords of my choosing, I was looking into the Google AdWords API particularly:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201609/TrafficEstimatorService

I was wondering how I can send a GET request to this API to actually get a response with the traffic (Either using PHP or Jquery)

```
https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/o/v201609/?keyword=test
```

doesnt seem to work

If not or this is impossible, how are certain sites getting search data and trends, How would i be able to see how many times a query, for example `Nickleback` has been searched (If possible, without OAUTH)